# Does initialising an auxiliary array to 0 count as n time complexity already?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

very new to big O complexity and I was wondering if an algorithm where you have a given array, and you initialise an auxilary array with the same amount of indexes count as n time already, or do you just assume this is O(1), or nothing at all?

Comment: How do you initialize it to 0 ? Share your code.

Comment: I mean initialising an array of say size n to 0 for every index

Comment: Share  your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Ignore it

**Long answer**: This will depend on the rest of your algorithm as well as what you want to achieve. Typically you will do something useful with the array afterwards which does have at least the same time complexity as filling the array, so that array-filling does not contribute to the time complexity. Furthermore filling an array with 0 feels like something you do to initialize the array, so your "real" algorithm can work properly. But nevertheless there are some cases you could consider.

Please note that I use pseudocode in the following examples, I hope it's clear what the algorithm should do. Also note that all the examples don't do anything useful with the array. It's just to show my point.

Lets say you have following code:

```
A = Array[n]
for(i=0, i<n, i++)
    A[i] = 0
print "Hello World"
```

Then obviously the runtime of your algorithm is highly dependent on the value of `n` and thus should be counted as linear complexity `O(n)`

On the other hand, if you have a much more complicated function, say this one:

```
A = Array[n]
for(i=0, i<n, i++)
    A[i] = 0
for(i=0, i<n, i++)
    for(j=n-1, j>=0, j--)
        print "Hello World"
```

Then even if you take the complexity of filling the array into account, you will end with complexity of `O(n^2+2n)` which is equal to the class `O(n^2)`, so it does not matter in this case.

The most interesting case is surely when you have different options to use as basic operation. Say we have the following code (`someFunction` being an arbitrary function):

```
A = Array[n*n]
for(i=0, i<n*n, i++)
    A[i] = 0
for(i=0, i*i<n, i++)
    someFunction(i)
```

Now it depends on what you choose as basic operation. Which one you choose is highly dependent on what you want to achieve. Let's say `someFunction` is a very cheap function (regarding time complexity) and accessing the array `A` is more expensive. Then you would propably go with `O(n^2)`, since accessing the array is done n^2 times. If on the other hand `someFunction` is expensive compared to filling the array, you would propably choose this as base operation and go with `O(sqrt(n))`.

Please be aware that one could also come to the conclusion that since the first part (array-filling) is executed more often than the other part (`someFunction`) it does not matter which one of the operations will take longer time to finish, since at some point the array-filling will need longer time. Thus you could argue that the complexity *has* to be quadratic `O(n^2)` This may be right from a theoretical view. But in real life you usually will have an operation you want to count and don't care about the other operations.

Actually you could consider ignoring the array filling as well as taking it into account in all the examples I provided above, depending whether `print` or accessing the array is more expensive. But I hope in the first two examples it is obvious which one will add more runtime and thus should be considered as the basic operation.